# Decision Tree algorithms in R packages

Tags: r, package, decision-tree

Is there any way to specify the algorithm used in any of the R packages for decision tree formation? I know that CART and C5.0 models are available. I want to find out about other decision tree algorithms such as ID3, C4.5 and OneRule algorithms.

EDIT: Due to the ambiguous nature of my question, I would like to clarify it. Is there some function (say fun()) which creates and trains a decision tree wherein we can specify the algorithm as a parameter of the function fun()?

Like for example, to find the correlation between two vectors, we have cor() where we can specify the method used as pearson, spearman or kendall.

Is there such a function for decision trees as well so we can use different algorithms like ID3, C4.5, etc?

Comment: There are multiple packages, some with multiple methods for creating a decision tree. Different packages may use different algorithms. Some of those packages and functions may allow choice of algorithm, and some may implement only one (and, of course, not all the same one). I would suggest just searching (using, for example, the `sos` package) for those algorithms to see what packages/functions implement them.

Comment: See the section on "Recursive Partitioning" in the "Machine Learning" task view on CRAN: http://CRAN.R-project.org/view=MachineLearning